# ¿Cómo agrego los elementos de un arreglo a otro arreglo más grande en Java?

Tags: java

Intenté algo como

```
array1=array2
```

pero según entiendo, eso hace que los arreglos sean iguales, incluso con el mismo tamaño. Pero lo que quiero es por ejemplo:

```
int datos [] = new int [5];
```

Lo que guarde ahí por ejemplo `1,2,3,4,5`.

Quisiera copiarlo a un arreglo mas grande

```
int auxiliar [] = new int [10];
```

Para poder acceder a esos mismos datos solo que en otro arreglo más grande.
Espero haberme explicado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que tienes que entender primero es como funciona un Array de datos, una de las principales características es que `los Array son de una dimensión fija`, esto tiene un trasfondo complejo pero en pocas palabras, cuando se trabaja con un array los espacios se reservan en memoria desde el momento de su creación y si se permitiera redimensionarlos el sistema tendría que verificar el espacio en memoria para determinar si es posible o se tendría que alojar en un nuevo espacio, eso es genera más consumo de recursos y latencia, según qué tipo de programación hagas (como sockets) te puede importar más o menos, para arreglos dinámicos se utilizan listas como por ejemplo ArrayList.

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo se unen 2 Arrays esto es más fácil o complejo según si utilizas tipos primitivos cono `int` u objetos como `Integer` para el arreglo, pero ambos métodos se basan el la misma premisa crear un nuevo array con el largo de los 2 array a unir y cargar dentro de este nuevo array los datos de ambos.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class JavaUnirArreglos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Uniendo Arrays de tipo primitivo int
        // Asigno los valores de esta forma para que se mas claro.
        int datosA [] = new int [5];
        datosA[0] = 0; 
        datosA[1] = 1; 
        datosA[2] = 2;  
        datosA[3] = 3; 
        datosA[4] = 4;

        int datosB [] = new int [5];
        datosB[0] = 5; 
        datosB[1] = 6; 
        datosB[2] = 7; 
        datosB[3] = 8; 
        datosB[4] = 9;

        int[] datosC = unirInt(datosA, datosB);
        System.out.println("union de int: " + Arrays.toString(datosC)); // Impresión de resultado.

       // Uniendo Arrays con Java 8+ Stream API

        Integer datosX [] = new Integer [5];
        datosX[0] = 0; 
        datosX[1] = 1; 
        datosX[2] = 2; 
        datosX[3] = 3; 
        datosX[4] = 4;

        Integer datosY [] = new Integer [5];
        datosY[0] = 5; datosY[1] = 6; datosY[2] = 7; datosY[3] = 8; datosY[4] = 9;

        Integer[] datosZ = unirIntegerStream(datosX, datosY);

        System.out.println("union de Integer: " + Arrays.toString(datosZ)); // Impresión de resultado.
    }

    public static int[] unirInt(int[] a, int[] b){
        //Obtenemos el largo de cada array
        int largoA = a.length;
        int largoB = b.length;

        // Creamos el nuevo array donde se uniran con la suma del largo de A y B
        int[] nuevoArray = new int[largoA + largoB];

        // Utilizamos el método System.arraycopy, pasamos el ArrayA
        // y que copie desde la posición 0 del ArrayA a la posición 0 del nuevoArray
        // el total del largo del ArrayA.
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, nuevoArray, 0, largoA);

        // Utilizamos el método System.arraycopy, pasamos el ArrayB
        // y que copie desde la posición 0 del ArrayB a la poscicion final que utilizo el ArrayA el largo total del ArrayB.
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, nuevoArray, largoA, largoB);

        return nuevoArray;
    }

    public static Integer[] unirIntegerStream(Integer[] x, Integer[] y){
        // Utilizamos la API Stream para recorrer los Array y crear uno nuevo.
        Integer[] union = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(x), Arrays.stream(y))
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);
        return union;
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] // con int
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] // con Integer
```

Comment: Gracias brother